# How do I calculate the capacity of a capacitor using measurements of an experiment?

Tags: voltage, capacitor, circuit-analysis, measurement, time

I build this circuit in an experiment
[image: circuit]

During the experiment I got these readings:

```
t (s)   0  10   20   30  40   50   60   70   80   90  100
U (V)   0 0,43 0,86 1,2 1,53 1,84 2,11 2,35 2,58 2,78 2,96

t (s) 110   120  130  140  150 160
U (V) 3,12 3,28 3,41 3,54 3,68 3,76
```

Can someone show me how to calculate the capacity of the capacitor c using these readings? The power supply is 5,34V.

Comment: It seems this is some kind of homework assignment. What have you done so far to figure this out?

Comment: Step 1: Plot the data. Step 2: determine the RC time constant of the circuit by reading of the time the output rises to x percent of the steady state value...

Comment: @sstobbe I ploted the data. the RC time constant for one tau is at 140s. How can a derive the capacity of c from that?

Comment: The capacitor will charge to 63.2% (1-1/exp(1)) in 1 \$\tau\$ . 5.34*0.632 = 3.37 V, So 1 \$\tau\$ would be less than 140 s, based on the data you presented.

Comment: @sstobbe I would say around 125s would be one tau.

Comment: you need to know the value of R to calculate C

Comment: @vicatcuh how can we get the value of R? We have to calculate C with the data we measured in the experiment or using the ploted data.

Comment: the measurement conditions Missy iframe been known, R being part of that.

Comment: @nmq \$C=\frac{\Delta Q}{\Delta V}=\frac{\frac{\text{d} Q}{\text{d} t}}{\frac{\text{d} V_\text{C}}{\text{d} t}}=\frac{I_\text{C}\left(t\right)}{\frac{\text{d} V_\text{C}}{\text{d} t}}\$. How do you propose to find \$I_\text{C}\left(t\right)\$ without \$R\$?

Comment: @nmq Since you agree that \$\tau\approx 125\:\text{s}\$, then you can say that \$R\cdot C\approx 125 \:\text{s}\$, or that \$C\approx \frac{125 \:\text{s}}{R}\$. Again, there is that missing \$R\$ value. No matter how you cut this, you need a quantity for \$R\$ to get a quantity for \$C\$.

Comment: @jonk that's our problem. we can't find a way to find R. Could you help us out?

Comment: @nmq What else are you allowed to do other than what you've already recorded?

Comment: The assignment is that we have to use the measurements or the plot of it to find C.

Comment: @nmq The quantitative (as opposed to qualitative) value of \$C\$ isn't possible without \$R\$. Your data can provide information about the combined pairing. But that cannot be used to separate the one from the other. You need more information. There is something else that you haven't told us about and that you may not even realize in important. Or else the question itself is flawed.

Answer (score 0):

Fit the curve to the known equation for the charging of a capacitor through a known resistance to a known voltage: V(t) = V * (1 - EXP(-t / (R * C))). Use Excel or similar and try different values of C until you find one that adequately fits your empirical data, then that must be your best guess at C.

Answer (score 0):

Well, using Mathematica I got:

[image]

So:

$$\text{RC}=124.33050942269067\tag1$$

Comment: The curve doesn't match the data, so the excessive precision of your answer is inappropriate.